# Simple QuickSort implementation with first element pivot and brute-force counting comparisons

Tags: java, quicksort

I'm using this simple implementation. I just want to count the comparisons. Below the code actually works.
The list is `[3, 9, 8, 4, 6, 10, 2, 5, 7, 1].`

The answer for comparison count is 25 but I'm getting 30. I can't figure out why. What causes this code to do "more work" than it is supposed to? Thanks in advance!

```
public void sort(int[] values){
    int length = values.length;

    if(values == null || length == 0){
        return;
    }

    quicksort(values, 0, length-1);
}

private int partition(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int i = left+1;

    int pivot = arr[left];

    for(int j=(left+1); j<=right; j++){
        comparisonCount++;
        if(arr[j] < pivot){
            swap(arr,i,j);
            i++;
        }
    }

    swap(arr,left, i-1);
    return i;
}

private void quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int index = partition(arr, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1){
        quicksort(arr, left, index-1);
    }

    if (index < right){
        quicksort(arr, index, right);
    }
}

private void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j){
    int tmp;
    tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes. Nothing has caught my attention yet.

Comment: Really? *Everything* you saw in debugging mode matched what you expected? So it appears the program appears to be printing `30` for no reason at all?

Comment: It didn't print 30 for no reason. It seems like nothing is wrong.

Comment: I mean, something evidently is. If you were to perform the quicksort algorithm yourself, and compare it to what the computer is doing, do you and the computer match up? You two have got to diverge *somewhere* if the final answer isn't what you expect...

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did the answer of 25 come from? Is it possible that your partitioning step works differently from the reference partition?

Comment: Gotcha. Indeed, I wrote it on paper. I'm still new to sorting algorithm. I'll try that approach again.

Comment: I'm doing assignment. I have this test case example and I'm running through it using file I/O.

Comment: I don't see any immediate flaws with the algorithm... Let me run this through a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I appear to have found where the discrepancy is coming from:

```
quicksort(values, 0, length - 1); // initial call in sort()
for (int j = (left + 1); j <= right; j++) { // loop in partition()
```

Versus

```
quicksort(values, 0, length); // initial call in sort()
for (int j = (left + 1); j < right; j++) { // loop in partition()
```

First one gives 30 comparisons, second gives 25.

*Why* this is the case? I suspect it has something to do with how the loop invariant is set up. My guess is that you're comparing some pivot multiple times due to the way the bounds were set up. I'm too brain-dead to figure out the exact bounds, so I'll try to remember to come back once I get that figured out.

Comment: Nice catch! Thank you. I remember I had this similar problem with bounds setting up. I always prefer i<something than i<=something when it comes to this situation. I feel like this is a common rookie mistake, isn't it?

Comment: @Matt Off-by-one errors is a mistake that anyone can make, not only rookies. Have to say though that rookies might come across them more frequently because you're reimplementing functions to learn them, where later in your programming career you'd use a library. Good way to avoid this is by making sure you know your loop invariant before coding, but even then it's easy to make a mistake, albeit if you do it's somewhat easier to catch. Have to say that `i < x` is probably Java/C/C++/C# convention more than anything; other languages (like MATLAB, if memory serves) actually prefer `i <= x`

Comment: Upvote! True, anyone could make that mistake. Interesting fact about Matlab.